# How can I split string to decimal to calculate?

Tags: jquery

I have a string format: 3,500,000 VNĐ

How can I use jquery to split it to 3500000.

I just know how to split it `split("VNĐ")` after that the result is `3,500,000 ,`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a regex like

```
var x = '3,500,000 VNĐ'.replace(/[,\s(VNĐ)]/g, '')
```

if you want x to be an int value then

```
var x = parseInt('3,500,000 VNĐ'.replace(/[,\s(VNĐ)]/g, ''), 10)
```

Comment: It works, but after calculate. How can i return to my original format.
And if i refresh the page. My value return and not work.

Answer (score 0):

As you have space between number and string, you can do this:

```
var str = "3,500,000 VNĐ";
var n = str.split(" "); //split by space
```

Then to remove `Comma(,)` again use split function:

```
var number = n[0].replace(/\,/g,""); //remove comma
```

Here is the [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rkb57/438/)

Comment: The result is 3,500,000. It doesn't split comma. And how i can return to orginal 3,500,000 VNĐ when success jquery code.